# Is this true and how to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a series $(u_n)$  that converges to $l$ and I am asked to say (and prove) whether or not $\left(\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right)$ converges to 1.

Intuitively I would say this is the case but I don't really know how to prove it.

With the definition of convergence, I think a good start might be to try proving that:
$$(\forall \epsilon > 0) (\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n > N),\ \left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} - 1\right| < \epsilon$$

Is there an easy way of doing that following my idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily; issues arise when $\ell=0$. For example, let $u_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$.  Then $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \frac{1}{2}$ for every $n$.

However, if $\ell \neq 0$, then 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}} = \frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}{u_{n+1}}}{\lim_{n\to \infty}{u_n}} = \frac{\ell}{\ell} = 1$$

Comment: It's worth noting for the OP that the manipulation in the last line is justified by continuity of $1/x$ at $l$ and since the product of convergent sequences converges to the product of the limits.

Comment: Thank you ! Didn't thought the answer could be so simple !!